# mysql upgrading from 5.1 --> 5.6 do I have to do mysqldump before upgrade?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump, upgrade, mysql-5.1

I was reading this document: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

It says when upgrading from mysql 5.1 to do a mysqldump and then a reload. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Skipping a major version is not supported. It might work. The backups are to be made ​​in any case, even if you don't plan to upgrade. There are too many things that can go wrong. Here a recent blog post of mysql employee about upgrade http://www.tocker.ca/2015/03/12/making-the-case-to-support-2-version-upgrades.html

Comment: Thanks for the article. It sounds like going from one major version to the next is supported. Follow up: if I create a dump file from 5.1 and then test in 5.6; and it works; is this safe to do?

Comment: That's not quite the same.  Can you load the dump into a 5.1 on another system, then upgrade to 5.6 on there?

Comment: In any case, be sure to run mysql_upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I have addressed something like this already

- `Oct 17, 2014` : [Any known issues upgrading from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.21?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80499/any-known-issues-upgrading-from-mysql-5-1-73-to-5-6-21/80503#80503)
- `Jan 31, 2014` : [Upgrading mysql myisam 5.1 to mysql 5.6: force innodb on restore?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/upgrading-mysql-myisam-5-1-to-mysql-5-6-force-innodb-on-restore/57989#57989)
- `Apr 11, 2013` : [MySQL upgrade 5.0.88 to latest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39716/mysql-upgrade-5-0-88-to-latest/39763#39763)
- `Feb 08, 2012` : [will replication from 5.5.20 to 5.0.XX server work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12509/will-replication-from-5-5-20-to-5-0-xx-server-work/12511#12511)
- `Jul 26, 2011` : [Restoring an old backup to latest MySQL release](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/restoring-an-old-backup-to-latest-mysql-release/4127#4127)

Leaping two versions is risky if you do not want to run mysql_upgrade twice. My `Oct 17, 2014` post mentions running mysql_upgrade twice, the right way.

In your case, you should do this:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="set group_concat_max_len = 1048576;"
SQL="${SQL} select group_concat(schema_name) from information_schema.schemata"
SQL="${SQL} where schema_name not in"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
DBLIST=`mysql -ANe"${SQL}" | sed 's/,/ /g'`
mysqldump --databases ${DBLIST} > MySQLData.sql
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',"
SQL="${SQL} QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';') "
SQL="${SQL} FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > GetGrants.sql
echo "SET sql_log_bin = 0;" > MySQLGrants.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN < GetGrants.sql | sed 's/$/;/g' >> MySQLGrants.sql
rm -f GetGrants.sql
```

Now just load `MySQLGrants.sql` and `MySQLData.sql` into the MySQL 5.6 instance.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Can you point me to a document from mysql team that says you can do a dump from 5.1 --> 5.6x and not have issues? A lot of the upgrade docs don't talk about versions that are this far apart.

Comment: If I knew where such documentation were, I would not have written all these posts.